# Audio streaming from Android to VLC on PC

Tags: android, stream, audio, streaming, vlc

The method bellow captures on slice of sound and saves it:

```
MediaRecorder.setOutputFile(PATH);
```

I want to stream sound. So I need capture sound frame by framef to send across the network. How I can do it?

How I can capture sound frame by frame?

Answer (score 2):

I found one class enable to do this. AudioRecord.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html

this class capture de sound and put it in a buffer in memory, so you can use this buffer to send by network in livestream or whatever you want.